# How do I have ReSharper require braces unless the using statement has nested using statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

In ReSharper you can require that `Using` statements have braces if it is a single line using statement or a multi-line.
`Options` => `Code Editing` => `C#` => `Code Style` => `Braces` => `In single-statement "using"`

Is it possible to require braces for single statement `Using` like this:

```
using (var disposableA = new DisposableA())  {  
    //single line using disposableA...
}
```

but not require braces when the single statement is a nested `Using` statement?

```
using (var disposableB = new DisposableB())
using (var disposableC = new DisposableC())
{
    //code that uses disposableB & disposableC...
}
```

I *do not* want to allow this kind of statement in the code

```
using (var disposableD = new DisposableD())  
    //single line using disposableD...
```